# Find the number of vertices that belong to all the maximum matchings of a general connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

The given graph is connected but not necessarily bipartite. Please describe the complete approach with useful links , I read stuff related to augmenting paths but could not comprehend well.
An O(VE) approach will be good for me .
Though i would prefer O(V^2) approach (if it is known)

Comment: The naive approach is to iteratively delete each vertex and check if the maximum matching is still the same size, which I guess gives $O(V^{1.5} E)$. Is $O(V^2)$ known even for finding a single maximum matching?

Comment: After Finding a single maximum matching we just need O(V+E) to find the answer. 
Also I read it somewhere , it is possible using Disjoint SET-Union DS for Edmond`s algo. Looking for an explanation.